# Force Eclipse SVN to check files changed outside Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, svn

I am working on a project containing java and c++ files. The java files are edited in Eclipse, and c++ files in Visual Studio. I use SVN on Eclipse to commit changed files into repository. There is no problem with files edited in Eclipse itself, however, the files edited outside Eclipse are not recognized as changed (outgoing) unless I open them in Eclipse. Is there a way to force Eclipse to check all the files for changes, so that I do not need to keep track of changed c++ files myself?

Comment: using "refresh" on the folder containing the changed files will probably work

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks. That actually works! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "refresh" command on the folder containing the changed files.